# Unpacking variables in python

Tags: python

full code:

```
scores = []
choice = None

while choice != "0": #while choice isnt 0 options will be printed to user and
#the user will have an opportunity to pick a choice 0-2
    print("""
    High Scores 2.0

    0 - Quit
    1 - List Scores
    2 - Add a Score
    """)

    choice = input("Choice: ")
    print()

    #display high-score table
    if choice == "1":
        print("High Scores\n")
        print("NAME\tSCORE")
        for entry in scores: 
            score,name = entry
            print(name, "\t", score)

    #add a score
    elif choice == "2":
        name = input("What is the player's name: ")
        score = int(input("What score did the player get: "))
        entry = (score, name)
        scores.append(entry)
        scores.sort(reverse = True)
        scores = scores[:5] #Keeps only top 5 scores

#exit
if choice == "0":
    print("Goodbye")
```

My question is why do:

```
for entry in scores: 
    score,name = entry
    print(name, "\t", score)
```

and

```
for entry in scores: 
        entry= score,name
        print(name, "\t", score)
```

both work properly?
Im pretty confused on unpacking and am not sure why both of those pieces of code work properly could someone please explain?

Comment: The latter definitely does not work.

Comment: I did not expect it to but i ran it again and it did not generate and error?

Comment: If you were to run the code in isolation it would give you an error. The reason why python didn't complain is probably because you also assign to `name` and `score` elsewhere, i.e. when `choice == "2"`, but the behavior would still be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why do:

```
for entry in scores: 
    score,name = entry
    print(name, "\t", score)
```

> and

```
for entry in scores: 
        entry= score,name
        print(name, "\t", score)
```

> work properly?

the first one works properly and is valid python, but the second one should not work at all. It should raise a `NameError` saying that `score` and `name` do not exist.

About the *first one*, *unpacking*, also known as a *destructuring assignment* works as follows:

on the right hand side you have an *iterable*, and on the left hand side a *tuple*, each element of the left hand side *tuple* gets affected with elements of the *iterable*. If you have too many elements to assign to, you get a `ValueError: too many elements to unpack`.

i.e.:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> foo, bar, foobar = mylist
>>> print foo, bar, foobar
1 2 3
```

which is equivalent to:

```
>>> foo, bar, foobar = [1,2,3]
>>> print foo, bar, foobar
1 2 3
```

it's as simple as that!

*edit*

basically, what you are really doing is:

```
for entry in scores:
    print entry # here you shall see something like `('value1', 'value2')`
    score,name = entry
    print(name, "\t", score)
```

each entry being a tuple of (at least) two values contaning what you use as a score and a name.

resources to read:

- http://robert-lujo.com/post/40871820711/python-destructuring
- http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html
- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples
- http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/tuples.html

HTH

Comment: It isn't widely known that it's also possible to use unpacking assignment in for loops, so the first two lines of the OP's final example could be replaced by `for score, name in scores:`

Comment: the first one is working when i run it and i have no idea why

Comment: well, that's what I'm explaining to you in the last part of the question

Answer (score 0):

Your two code snippets do not do the same thing.

```
for entry in scores: 
    score,name = entry
    print(name, "\t", score)
```

This code snippet unpacks `entry` into the two variables `score` and `name`, which is probably what you want.

```
for entry in scores: 
    entry= score,name
    print(name, "\t", score)
```

This code snippet, on the other hand, assigns a tuple `(score,name)` to the variable `entry`. I can't imagine that this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to just do:

```
scores = [(10, 'Alice'), (5, 'Bob')]
for score, name in scores: 
    print(name, "\t", score)
```

Results:

```
10   Alice
5   Bob
```